# Z-index not workinging properly in Chrome, does in Firefox, IE8

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, z-index

I have searched, but cannot find a solution that works for me.
For this site: http://kohvik.ut.ee
I cannot get the z-index on the logo to work with Chrome. Firefox and IE8 can do this.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should work:

```
jQuery("#main-menu").find("div").css("z-index")
```

Weird thing is that you have 'div' inside of 'ul' as direct child, but nevermind. This should get your z-index attribute. (I hope that's what you meant by logo, if that's not your logo, please let me now which element do you mean by logo)

EDIT:

I've found it. Try setting **z-index to 1 to element with id 'main-leftarea'**. Set it to 1. It worked for me when I tried to change it in browser directly.

Comment: *"...but nevermind"*. This is invalid HTML and should be addressed.

Comment: I know it is...but he wanted answer for current HTML...I gave him that and instructed him that his HTML is wrong...so I don't see the point of your comment

Comment: Thanks for addressing the weird placement of the div. I fixed that. Unfortunately I the suggested jQuery does not solve my problem. The logo (center upper) is still behind the right hand area when using Chrome.

Comment: Check out edited part. It should work ok now with Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thank you! It finally worked! Thank you very much for your effort!